# Access openshift with iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, openshift

Is there a way to access to openshift with iphone/ipad and manage the applications through ssh? There is an app from openShift but only available for android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several apps available in the App Store. I use IFTP Pro and SSH Control.

Comment: Thanks. Should I have a private key on my iphone?

Comment: I used My key that I use on my PC that I created with putty.